# jQuery datepicker integration with TYPO3 Flow

Tags: jquery, datepicker, typo3, typo3-flow

Any idea how to get the jQuery datepicker working in TYPO3 Flow?

I integrated the picker in the fluid-view and defined the mysql-row as \DateTime.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd.m.yy'
});
```

the model:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Flow\Validate(type="NotEmpty")
 */
protected $tourStart;
```

In the controller I have to convert the string:

```
/**
 * Initialize 
 * @return void
 */
public function initializeCreateAction() {
    $tourStartMappingConf = $this->arguments->getArgument('tour')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
    $tourStartMappingConf->allowProperties('tourStart', 'tourEnd');
    $tourStartMappingConf->setTypeConverterOption(
        'TYPO3\Flow\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter',
        \TYPO3\Flow\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT,
        'd.m.Y'
        );
}
```

That doesn't seem to work.

> Error:
>   tourStart The date "14.11.2014" was not recognized (for format "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP").
>   tourStart is required

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the forProperty(). Here is how it could look in initializeCreateAction:

```
$this->arguments['tour']
->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
->forProperty('tourStart')
->setTypeConverterOption('TYPO3\Flow\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter', \TYPO3\Flow\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT, 'd.m.Y');
```

I assume 'tour' is the param name for the createAction and 'tourStart' is the property.

Comment: Your are right.. I had to split the conversion and seperate 'tourStart' and 'tourEnd'.. But i couldn't figure out the reason for that.. anyway now it works..